# Finding an inner product given a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a norm $|\cdot |$, find the inner product for which $\langle v,v\rangle=|v|$.

So basically I need to find an inner product such that $\forall v\in V. \langle v,v\rangle=1$, right? How do I do that?

I was also given a hint: "Find a way to write $\langle u,v\rangle$ as a function of norms." I think they mean $\langle u,v\rangle= \dfrac{|u+v|^2-|u|-|v|}{2}$?

Comment: Yes. Or $\frac14(\lVert u+v\rVert-\lVert u-v\rVert)$.

Answer (score 1):

The parallelogram law says for a norm from an inner product, $2 || x||^2 + 2 ||y||^2 = ||x-y||^2 + ||x+y||^2$.

You can get from this the polarization identity $$\langle x,y\rangle = \frac{||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2}{4}$$

Comment: There is also a polarization identity for complex norms.

Comment: Yeah. There's a lot of them -- you can get a different one from considering the $n$-th primitive roots of unity for each $n\geq 3$.